# jQuery: Setting string for function call

Tags: jquery

My code seems flawed, I'm setting two functions with the same code inside. Can I combine them into one?

```
// remove sets
$('body').on("click", "span.remove", function() {

    var self  = $(this),
        total = self.parents('ul').children('li').size(); // grab total number of li's

    // remove (set) li if total greater than 1, else remove exercise
    if(total > 1)
        self.parent('li').fadeOut('slow', function() {

            // remove clicked .li and reset list order
            $(this).remove();
            reset();

        });

    else
        self.parents('section').fadeTo('slow', 0.33).slideUp('slow', function() {

            // remove clicked .li and reset list order
            $(this).remove();
            reset();

        });

});
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
if(total > 1)
    var f = self.parent('li').fadeOut('slow', function()

else
    var f = self.parents('section').fadeTo('slow', 0.33).slideUp('slow', function()

f {

    // remove clicked .li and rest list order
    $(this).remove();
    reset();

});
```

Comment: Sure, just pass `f` instead of `function(){ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a named function, instead of an anonymous function. A named function can then be passed around by reference, including as a parameter to other methods. There are two ways to do this, either as an expression (`function someName(){..}`) or an assignment (`var someName = function() {..}`). Which you choose is mainly personal preference, they are effectively the same.

An example (using a function expression), following on from your question below:

```
$('body').on("click", "span.remove", function() {

    function removeAndReset() {
            // remove clicked .li and reset list order
            $(this).remove();
            reset();
    }

    var self  = $(this),
        total = self.parents('ul').children('li').size(); // grab total number of li's

    // remove (set) li if total greater than 1, else remove exercise
    if(total > 1)
        self.parent('li').fadeOut('slow', removeAndReset);

    else
        self.parents('section').fadeTo('slow', 0.33).slideUp('slow', removeAndReset);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on("click", "span.remove", function() {

    var self  = $(this),
        total = self.parents('ul').children('li').size(); // grab total number of li's

    function remove() {
        $(this).remove();
        reset();
    }
    // remove (set) li if total greater than 1, else remove exercise
    if(total > 1)
        self.parent('li').fadeOut('slow', remove);

    else
        self.parents('section').fadeTo('slow', 0.33).slideUp('slow', remove);

});
```